# How can I put another Object in the Opportunity validation rule?

Tags: opportunity, validation, validation-rule, account-teams

I'm trying to allow only the Account's Owner and Account Team Members "001" to create opportunities.
But I'm getting "The AccountTeamMember field does not exist".

How can I solve it?

```
OR($User.Id <> Account.Owner.Id,
VLOOKUP(AccountTeamMember.TeamMemberRole, AccountTeamMember.UserId,$User.Id)<> "001")
```

Comment: Pretty sure you are going to need to move the validation to code if you want to exempt the Account Team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible...
I had to create an Apex Class.